# how do I put all of my graphs on one plane

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

My program is using Euler's method to Sketch the graph of  ()  and the approximations ℎ ()  with  ℎ=1,0.5,0.1  for the time interval  [0,30]  on the same plane. However, I'm new to python and I don't know how to put all of the graphs onto one plane.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def Eulergraph(h,N):
    K = 12; r = 0.43; Po = 1;
```

Instead of three graphs, I need it all the graphs in one plane.

Comment: When you paste code into a question (or answer), immediately select it and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface to format it properly. I've fixed it for you here.

Comment: I have a great matplotlib quick reference pdf that I'm trying to find a link for. If not I'll upload it somewhere and link it..

Comment: [Here's](https://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/~stevel/cheatsheets/Matplotlib%20Notes_8pages.pdf) the cheat sheet I always use for `matplotlib` graphing. I keep it on every computer I code on...

Comment: thanks, but I'm still getting an error using the axis object that's not letting me compile.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: actually, nevermind it works good

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the axis object (called `ax` below) to the `Eulergraph` function and then merely call `plt.show` once:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# your function
def Eulergraph(h, N, ax):
    ...

    for n in range(N+1):
        Pn = P[n] + h*f(P[n])
        P = np.append(P,Pn)
        # Note the change here
        ax.plot ( n, P[n] , ' ro' )

# create your figure and axis object
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

# pass the axis object as a parameter
Eulergraph(1,30,ax)       
Eulergraph(.5,30,ax)   
Eulergraph(.1,30,ax)

# formatting of your plot
plt.xlabel (' Value of n ”' )
plt.ylabel (" Value of p[n] ”")
plt.title (" Approximate Solution with Euler’s Method " )
plt.show()
```

Note that you can also **not** call `plt.show()` within your function and that would have the desired effect. However, I'd recommend writing the function to accept an axis argument as you can then choose at a later stage to separate the plots onto different graphs.

---

From the [docs for plt.show](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html):

> Display a figure. When running in ipython with its pylab mode, display all figures and return to the ipython prompt.

So a little example shows that you can plot two lines on the same figure:

exp1.py:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y1 = np.arange(10)*2-1
y2 = np.arange(10)*1+1

plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

Running `exp1.py` has the desired effect of one figure with both lines:
[image]

However, changing the script to call `plt.show` twice will result in two separate plots e.g.,

```
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.show()
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

The `plt.show()` function displays the figure (with all plots defined to that point in time) and further plots will then create new figures.

Comment: That's fair. On it